What are the trades off for implementing recursion as a problem solving tool?
I implemented a simple recursive average calculator in C++, where the 'Student' must enter their grades and the function returns their Average. But I'm wondering if I have any advantage to using recursion other than not using it.
Here's the code:
/*
*@brief This code is an implementation of a recursive media calculator function which was made 
* for practice Algorithms and Data Structure.
* Autor: Kayque Amado
* Date: 19/04/2024
*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define NUM_GRADES 5

uint8_t control = 0;
float media = 0;

float Media(int *grade);

int main()
{
    int grades[NUM_GRADES];
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_GRADES; i++) //grades input
    {
        cin >> grades[i];
    }
    Media(grades);
    cout << "Media: " << media;
    return 0;
}

float Media(int *grade)
{
    if(control == NUM_GRADES) //base case
    {       
        media = media/NUM_GRADES;
        return media;
    }
    else{                     //recursive case
        media += *grade;
        control++;
        grade++;
        return Media(grade); 
    }
    return 0;
}


I expect just to understand more about this kind of problem-solving tool.

For this use-case, there's really no advantage over a plain loop. A plain loop will be simpler and likely more effective.

The general rule is that recursion should only be used when stricly required. If a direct iterative way is possible it is almost always both more simple and more efficent that a recursive way.

Recursion is a powerful analytical tool; it's almost always a poor coding tool.

My rule: the maximum recursion depth for a recursive function shall be O(log n). Having a O(n) depth like this implementation is asking for trouble: it will quickly crash with (not so) big n. And this type of recursive function can be very easily converted to a loop, that is easier to understand, easier to debug, safer and faster.

Recursion always eats up more stack space than iterative ones, and stackspace may be in short supply on (embedded) systems. Any recursive algorithm can be rewritten as an iterative one and the other way around so they are in a way equivalent. As for your system... who knows... you will have to do measurements.

Side note before worrying about performance, you should learn how to write "C++" instead of "C". You still use "C" style arrays and pointer decay, just don't. Use std::array<int,NGRADES> or in your case just std::vector<int>.

It's never too soon to stop using global variables, in particular in combination with recursion.

@molbdnilo I agree :) Same is true for not mixing floating point and integer math

A lot of it boils down to the tools you're using. If you were using a language with robust support for tail-call optimization, recursion becomes a more palatable option. For better or worse, C++ does not guarantee that

@PepijnKramer Thanks for your comments, Do you have any advice for me, which just started to learn C++?

@KayqueAmado the tag wiki for C++ here on Stack Overflow is a good resource.

Some good resources to learn C++ from are learncpp.com for your initial steps (it is very decent for an online tutorial).
Then use cppreference to lookup everything C++ has to offer.
And finally use the C++ core guidelines to keep up to date with how C++ evolves and how it is supposed to be used.

There are problems where recursion is a "natural" way of doing it, like traversal of a tree -- trying to do it in an iterative fashion usually leads to you explicitly tracking the path in a more convoluted way than the "natural" stack usage when doing it recursively.
Heck, couple millennia ago, I implemented a recursive algorithm in the good old 8K-Basic, simulating the recursion with an array-variable acting as a stack, because the computers back then only had a tiny stack. Nowadays, you can use actual recursion (usually) instead of doing that.
However, for problems where this is not the case, like calculating a factorial, the iterative loop is generally easier to read/understand, and unless the compiler detects and eliminates the recursion, also more efficient.
In other words, only use recursion when it makes things easier; don't do the "textbook"-recursion where some computer-science textbook shows you a recursive implementation for getting the length of a string (you know, the length of a string is 0 for an empty string, or 1 plus the length of the string with the first character removed). These are academic examples with no practical use.
In fact, going back to the tree -- if, instead of traversing it, you only want to look for a node, then the non-recursive version is suddenly the better choice since you can just update your one single pointer with either the left or the right child until you reach the node you need.
